# if-else python difference of two codes

Tags: python

May I ask what is the difference of these two codes(1 & 2 below)? They yield different results...But I think they are the same

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],"B":[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],"C":[11, 22, 33, 44, 55],"D":[12, 24, 51, 36, 2]})

num_pairs = [(1,5),(2,10),(3,15),(4,20),(5,25)]
num_range = list(range(8,16))
```

below are the two methods:

1.

```py
df['E'] = [num_pair[0] if num_pair[1] in num_range else 0 for num_pair in num_pairs]
```

2. 

```py
for num_pair in num_pairs:
    if num_pair[1] in num_range:
        df['E']= num_pair[0]
    else: 
        df['E'] = 0
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: In the second example you are assigning the entire column `E` every iteration.  So since your last value is `0` I'm guessing the entire column ends up as zero.

Comment: To put it another way, it's the difference between `df['E'] = [ some_list ]` and `df['E'] = single_value`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the second code is updating the entire column every loop with a single value.  You can print your df during the iteration to see the behavior.

I've provided an example using `.at` that does what you think the code should be doing.

With that being said, the approach you posted of assigning the list to the column in a single line is best.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],"B":[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],"C":[11, 22, 33, 44, 55],"D":[12, 24, 51, 36, 2]})

num_pairs = [(1,5),(2,10),(3,15),(4,20),(5,25)]
num_range = list(range(8,16))

# Print each iteration to see what you are doing
for num_pair in num_pairs:
    if num_pair[1] in num_range:
        df['E']= num_pair[0]
    else: 
        df['E'] = 0
    print(df)

# This what you probably think you are doing
for i, num_pair in enumerate(num_pairs):
    if num_pair[1] in num_range:
        df.at[i,'E'] = num_pair[0]
    else: 
        df.at[i,'E'] = 0
```